# How to change the current directory graphically using the keyboard only?

Tags: linux, osx, directory, utilities

There was a program named NCD (Norton Change Directory) a few years ago that did a good job at helping me change directory back in the DOS days.

This programs displayed a tree, and you could navigate in the tree with the directional arrows, and even find directories with regex (substrings).

Which program is there today to do this task ? I found wcd (available on Ubuntu), but for some reason it doesn't change the CWD to what I choose in the tree view, it just displays it on stdout. I just have

```
-> /home/ant/arduino-0023/examples
```

when I hit enter, and the cwd has not changed.

I'm looking for a program that runs on Linux and OS X.

Comment: What about midnight commander?

Comment: It's OK if there is a way to exit with one keystroke that is not a function key (F10 and many other already taken) and no confirmation, and a tree view.

Comment: Zsh has a lot of ways to make completion very fancy. Maybe one of its settings or plugins would suit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong with the installation of wcd, and you are executing the wcd binary directly. It is important that wcd is executed via a shell function (bash) or alias (csh). Otherwise it is not possible to change the CWD. See also: http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/wcd.htm#installation.
I don't run Ubuntu myself, so I don't know how the default installation works.

Comment: You are right. I had not read the full man page for wcd, in particular the installation section.